# How do a reference a variable in another object

Tags: java, arraylist, field

I am an absolute programming beginner, and I am trying to learn Java from a book. I'm very confused.

The book has an exercise (this is like halfway through the chapter, so there's a lot building up to this, but I'll try to make it clear) that asks us to add a method to a class. Basically, we were given a prebuilt set of classes that are supposed to be like a simple auction program. So there is an array list which contains a list of bidders, how much they bid, and the lot number. This exercise asks us to add a method that will print out a list of the names of the winning bidders and the value of their bids.

Okay, that makes sense. I can wrap my mind around how it is supposed to work. I even wrote the following code: `

```
    /**
 * Exercise 4.48
 * for each item in the list of lots, get the highest bid.
 * if highest bid is not null, print the bidder and value
 * otherwise, print "lot not sold"
 */
 public void close()
{
    for(Lot lot : lots) {
        Bid highestBid = lot.getHighestBid();
        if(highestBid != null) {
            System.out.println(bidder, value);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Lot not sold.");
        }
    }
}
```

When try to compile it, it stops on bidder because I haven't defined the variable. So obviously I am supposed to tell it what "bidder" is supposed to mean. Bidder is the name of the variable in the "Person" object in the same program and is used throughout the project, but I'm still not clear on how to get it to understand that my "bidder" is the same "bidder." I assume that I will have the same issue with "value."

What am I missing?

Edited to make the code actually look like code.

As requested, here is the Person... class? (I'm not great with the terminology. I'll get there. Sorry.)

```
        /**
     * Maintain details of someone who participates in an auction.
     * @author David J. Barnes and Michael Kölling.
     * @version 2011.07.31
     */
    public class Person
    {
        // The name of this person.
        private final String name;

        /**
         * Create a new person with the given name.
         * @param name The person's name.
         */
        public Person(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        /**
         * @return The person's name.
         */
        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }

        **/**
     * A class to model an item (or set of items) in an
     * auction: a lot.
     * 
     * @author David J. Barnes and Michael Kölling.
     * @version 2011.07.31
     */
    public class Lot
    {
        // A unique identifying number.
        private final int number;
        // A description of the lot.
        private String description;
        // The current highest bid for this lot.
        private Bid highestBid;

        /**
         * Construct a Lot, setting its number and description.
         * @param number The lot number.
         * @param description A description of this lot.
         */
        public Lot(int number, String description)
        {
            this.number = number;
            this.description = description;
            this.highestBid = null;
        }

        /**
         * Attempt to bid for this lot. A successful bid
         * must have a value higher than any existing bid.
         * @param bid A new bid.
         * @return true if successful, false otherwise
         */
        public boolean bidFor(Bid bid)
        {
            if(highestBid == null) {
                // There is no previous bid.
                highestBid = bid;
                return true;
            }
            else if(bid.getValue() > highestBid.getValue()) {
                // The bid is better than the previous one.
                highestBid = bid;
                return true;
            }
            else {
                // The bid is not better.
                return false;
            }
        }

        /**
         * @return A string representation of this lot's details.
         */
        public String toString()
        {
            String details = number + ": " + description;
            if(highestBid != null) {
                details += "    Bid: " + 
                           highestBid.getValue();
            }
            else {
                details += "    (No bid)";
            }
            return details;
        }

        /**
         * @return The lot's number.
         */
        public int getNumber()
        {
            return number;
        }

        /**
         * @return The lot's description.
         */
        public String getDescription()
        {
            return description;
        }

        /**
         * @return The highest bid for this lot.
         *         This could be null if there is
         *         no current bid.
         */
        public Bid getHighestBid()
        {
            return highestBid;
        }
    }
    **

    /**
 * A class that models an auction bid.
 * It contains a reference to the Person bidding and the amount bid.
 * 
 * @author David J. Barnes and Michael Kölling.
 * @version 2011.07.31
 */
public class Bid
{
    // The person making the bid.
    private final Person bidder;
    // The value of the bid. This could be a large number so
    // the long type has been used.
    private final long value;

        /**
         * Create a bid.
         * @param bidder Who is bidding for the lot.
         * @param value The value of the bid.
         */
        public Bid(Person bidder, long value)
        {
            this.bidder = bidder;
            this.value = value;
        }

        /**
         * @return The bidder.
         */
        public Person getBidder()
        {
            return bidder;
        }

        /**
         * @return The value of the bid.
         */
        public long getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }
    }


    import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * A simple model of an auction.
     * The auction maintains a list of lots of arbitrary length.
     *
     * @author David J. Barnes and Michael Kölling.
     * @version 2011.07.31
     * 
     * 3/12/15 added close method exercise 4.48
     * 
     */

        public class Auction
        {
            // The list of Lots in this auction.
            private ArrayList<Lot> lots;
            // The number that will be given to the next lot entered
            // into this auction.
            private int nextLotNumber;

            /**
             * Create a new auction.
             */
            public Auction()
            {
                lots = new ArrayList<Lot>();
                nextLotNumber = 1;
            }

            /**
             * Enter a new lot into the auction.
             * @param description A description of the lot.
             */
            public void enterLot(String description)
            {
                lots.add(new Lot(nextLotNumber, description));
                nextLotNumber++;
            }

            /**
             * Show the full list of lots in this auction.
             */
            public void showLots()
            {
                for(Lot lot : lots) {
                    System.out.println(lot.toString());
                }
            }

            /**
             * Make a bid for a lot.
             * A message is printed indicating whether the bid is
             * successful or not.
             * 
             * @param lotNumber The lot being bid for.
             * @param bidder The person bidding for the lot.
             * @param value  The value of the bid.
             */
            public void makeABid(int lotNumber, Person bidder, long value)
            {
                Lot selectedLot = getLot(lotNumber);
                if(selectedLot != null) {
                    Bid bid = new Bid(bidder, value);
                    boolean successful = selectedLot.bidFor(bid);
                    if(successful) {
                        System.out.println("The bid for lot number " +
                                           lotNumber + " was successful.");
                    }
                    else {
                        // Report which bid is higher.
                        Bid highestBid = selectedLot.getHighestBid();
                        System.out.println("Lot number: " + lotNumber +
                                           " already has a bid of: " +
                                           highestBid.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }

            /**
             * Return the lot with the given number. Return null
             * if a lot with this number does not exist.
             * @param lotNumber The number of the lot to return.
             */
            public Lot getLot(int lotNumber)
            {
                if((lotNumber >= 1) && (lotNumber < nextLotNumber)) {
                    // The number seems to be reasonable.
                    Lot selectedLot = lots.get(lotNumber - 1);
                    // Include a confidence check to be sure we have the
                    // right lot.
                    if(selectedLot.getNumber() != lotNumber) {
                        System.out.println("Internal error: Lot number " +
                                           selectedLot.getNumber() +
                                           " was returned instead of " +
                                           lotNumber);
                        // Don't return an invalid lot.
                        selectedLot = null;
                    }
                    return selectedLot;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Lot number: " + lotNumber +
                                       " does not exist.");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            /**
             * Exercise 4.48
             * for each item in the list of lots, get the highest bid.
             * if highest bid is not null, print the bidder and value
             * otherwise, print "lot not sold"
             */
             public void close()
            {
                for(Lot lot : lots) {
                    Bid highestBid = lot.getHighestBid();
                    if(highestBid != null) {
                        System.out.println(bidder, value);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Lot not sold.");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you please add the code with the Person class/object?

Comment: In order to help you you must really give some more code. Because this is missing out on a lot of external things that are not given here.

Comment: We don't need all the external code, but please do provide us with the entire project structure... how does a `Lot` class look like ? , ... -- Something else, in your method `close()` you call both `bidder`and `value` i assume they are class variables withing the class of that method ? if not, then that is your problem

Comment: They are not, but they are referenced elsewhere. I'm not sure how to describe the whole thing - I have actually literally no experience with this other than reading chapters 1-3.

Comment: We also need the Bid class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarifying your question by providing the supporting code!

This should fix your problem. Change this line:

```
System.out.println(bidder, value);
```

to this:

```
System.out.println(highestBid.getBidder().getName() + " bids " + highestBid.getValue())
```

The highestBid variable stores an object of type Bid. You can see the Bid class definition to see what it means for an object to have type Bid. Basically, a Bid object has a method called getValue(), which returns the value of the bid, and a method getBidder(), which returns a Person object (an object that abides by the Person class definition). So, look in the Person class and see how a Person object has a method called getName(), which returns the name of the person as a String.

Finally, we can just print the name and value with our handy built-in System.out.println() function.

Comment: It seems to like that okay. Thank you.

Comment: I was wrong. Now when I try to compile it, it says "cannot find symbol - variable bid" while hilighting the bid in System.out.println(bid.getBidder().getName(), bid.getValue());

Comment: Sorry, change bid to highestBid. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To teach you the very basic,

Consider a class as a real life object,
It has it own characteristics which you define as `class variables`.

These should be (generally) defined private so a call to them has to happen from a class-function (getters and setters). The reason why we do this is so you can setup some restrictions. (like: "not higher than 3" or "must be min. 4 char. long" ...)

The class functions are like: small hidden classes within a Class they execute some code. Notice the "In", functions IN class. not the other way around. So the variables you create inside the functions are not known to the class, but the function knows the class-variables.

I would suspect in your case that you called to `bidder`and `value`:

- Without use of getters if they are defined private outside the same class where your `close()` function is defined.

But really it is very hard for us to know what is wrong. Please provide us with the classof the `close()` function

EDIT:

the code for `close()`should be...

```
public void close()
        {
            for(Lot lot : lots) {
                Bid highestBid = lot.getHighestBid();
                if(highestBid != null) {
                    System.out.println(highestBid.getBidder(), highestBid.getValue());
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Lot not sold.");
                }
            }
```

Comment: The close() function is in the Auction class. I have provided it above.

Comment: Yes, like i said... you are trying to access the private class variables, they are defined private meaning only the class itself knows of its existance. You should make use of the public getter functions. i'll add the right code for close() to my answer above

Comment: If you do not understand the code please let me know

Comment: @GillianWeisgram if this answer seems correct or helpfull it is good if you accept or upvote it so that other people can enjoy of the knowlage...